# Django 1.0.2 extention for VS code disables html.autoClosingTags

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I found out that installing [Django 1.0.2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bigonesystems.django&ssr=false) extention on VS code disables the default html.autoClosingTags, meaning that, even if this is set to True, it won't autoclose HTML tags.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?
Or at least another extention highlighting django syntax that does not disable html.autoClosingTags.

### UPDATE:

As suggested by @Nadim Al Abdou
In my settings.json (File>Preferences>Settings> settings.json) there was:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Applicazioni_Tommaso\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
    "workbench.tree.indent": 30,
    "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\users\\tommaso",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,

},
```

I turn it into:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Applicazioni_Tommaso\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
    "workbench.tree.indent": 30,
    "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\users\\tommaso",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,

    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
        },
    
        "emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},

},
```

close and re-open vs code, but it does not work.

### Update:

This does not work because I am editing the User settings

1. press ctrl+p
2. insert `>open settings` in the search bar
3. select `preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`

while it is now clear that I should edit the Default settings

1. press ctrl+p
2. insert `>open settings` in the search bar
3. select `preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`

where I actually found the `"files.associations": {` line.

The problem is I cannot edit the file, beacuse as I try to, vscode shows the message: "cannot edit in read only editor".

What can I do to insert the line `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},` ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit your global settings.json file like so

1.

```
"files.associations": {
"**/*.html": "html",
"**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
"**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
"**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},
```

2.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
```

Comment: It did not worked. Please see the details in my edited question.

Comment: `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created this extension in one day, I'm adding more features, I saw you are adding:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "django-html" : "html" }
```

I tried adding it and is working for me. To be honest I'm not sure Why this is not working for you, Did you resolve it?

Can you try updating VSCode please? This info is helpful for me.

Another way is moving up the line, exactly before:

```
"files.associations": {
```

Thanks,

Roberth.

Comment: I was opening the wrong settings.json file. Here is what I do now: ctrl+p -> type inside the bar: ">open settings" -> select "preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)". The big JSON file opens and I go to the line where   "files.associations": {   is, but I can't add  
 "emmet.includeLanguages": { "django-html" : "html" }    because it says: "cannot edit in read only editor". How can I go on?